# Delphi XE7 Android Fullscreen (hide softkeys)

Tags: android, delphi, fullscreen, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

How to Fullscreen in XE7, hiding both the top (title) and bottom (softkey) toolbar?

In XE6 I could adjust the AndroidManifest to make my application go fullscreen and without the actionbar by writing in the application section:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

In XE7 this did no longer do the job, I found a Russian website with more information on the matter. Here is the first 'static' option:

> Suppose the situation: The application should always work in full
>   screen mode. Solution: Go to the menu "Project-> Options-> Version
>   Info (Android)" (For those who do not know, I have already described
>   this window here ), where we find the option «theme» and set his value
>   «No TitleBar». Everything now your application will always work in
>   full screen mode.

[Source](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fdelphifmandroid.blogspot.co.at%2F2014%2F09%2Fxe6.html)

Using the above source's method, the application launches in Fullscreen, hiding both bottom and top bar. But as soon as I change to another form both of the bars pop back up again and will never go away.

What is the correct way to hide the top and bottom bar so that my application will always run in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually found this out a while ago. In XE7 it's rather simple.

To hide the buttons, you can go to "Project/Options/Version Info/" and there set the Theme to "No TitleBar".

With the form set FullScreen to True.

The only minor issue is that sometimes the Softkeys do come back and leaves FullScreen when you have a usb-mouse attached and use the right mouse button, which will trigger a back-soft-button click.